# docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create shim task

Tags: docker, ubuntu, server

I have installed docker in my Ubuntu Server. But, when i run `docker run hello-world` this error message showed

> docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: error during container init: error mounting "proc" to rootfs at "/proc": mount proc:/proc (via /proc/self/fd/6), flags: 0xe: permission denied: unknown. ERRO[0000] error waiting for container: context canceled

How can i fix this ?

- Ubuntu 20.04
- Docker v20.10.22
- Docker Info Output:

```
Client:
 Context:    default
 Debug Mode: false
 Plugins:
  app: Docker App (Docker Inc., v0.9.1-beta3)
  buildx: Docker Buildx (Docker Inc., v0.9.1-docker)
  scan: Docker Scan (Docker Inc., v0.23.0)

Server:
 Containers: 9
  Running: 0
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 9
 Images: 1
 Server Version: 20.10.22
 Storage Driver: overlay2
  Backing Filesystem: extfs
  Supports d_type: true
  Native Overlay Diff: false
  userxattr: false
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
 Cgroup Version: 1
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
  Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
 Swarm: inactive
 Runtimes: runc io.containerd.runc.v2 io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux
 Default Runtime: runc
 Init Binary: docker-init
 containerd version: 9ba4b250366a5ddde94bb7c9d1def331423aa323
 runc version: v1.1.4-0-g5fd4c4d
 init version: de40ad0
 Security Options:
  apparmor
  seccomp
   Profile: default
 Kernel Version: 5.4.78-2-pve
 Operating System: Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS
 OSType: linux
 Architecture: x86_64
 CPUs: 2
 Total Memory: 8GiB
 Name: CT109
 ID: WQC6:HBSP:ZMPA:W7MM:56AM:PU5E:63XF:TMFO:RJN5:WGNQ:V7GB:KLW6
 Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
 Debug Mode: false
 Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
 Labels:
 Experimental: false
 Insecure Registries:
  127.0.0.0/8
 Live Restore Enabled: false
```

- Docker Version Output:

```
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           20.10.22
 API version:       1.41
 Go version:        go1.18.9
 Git commit:        3a2c30b
 Built:             Thu Dec 15 22:28:08 2022
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Context:           default
 Experimental:      true

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          20.10.22
  API version:      1.41 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.18.9
  Git commit:       42c8b31
  Built:            Thu Dec 15 22:25:58 2022
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.6.14
  GitCommit:        9ba4b250366a5ddde94bb7c9d1def331423aa323
 io.containerd.runc.v2:
  Version:          1.1.4
  GitCommit:        v1.1.4-0-g5fd4c4d
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0
```

i have installed qemu-kvm, libvirt-clients, libvirt-daemon-system

Comment: Do you know how to fix it? I got the same trouble, thank you, bro.

Answer (score 0):

I got it. You don't have the access to `/proc`. Use `chmod a+rw /proc` and `chown`, you will fix it.

Comment: I have the same issue but can't solve it. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Not working for me.
`root@VM302:~# chmod a+rw /proc
chmod: changing permissions of '/proc': Operation not permitted`


`root@VM302:~# sudo chmod a+rw /proc
chmod: changing permissions of '/proc': Operation not permitted`